# Trying to call on a superclass method, but pass a subclass's parameters?

Tags: java, inheritance

Sorry new to Java may not have described it quite right. Creating a text based adventure

Basically I have a super class named GameCharacter. Two subclasses Player and Monster. Monster has four subclasses Ork, Troll, Goblin, and the Boss

I have an abstract method called takeTurn() found in the super class. I have the fleshed out methods within the subclasses.  So when it comes to calling take turn, how do I know it will access the right subclass?

My super class

```
public abstract class GameCharacter{

    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract int getHealth();
    public abstract int getAttackPower();

   protected String gameCharacterName;
   protected int gameCharacterHealth;
   protected int gameCharacterAttack;

     public GameCharacter(String name, int health, int attack){
            this.gameCharacterName = name;
            this.gameCharacterHealth = health;
            this.gameCharacterAttack = attack;
     }

    public abstract void takeTurn(GameCharacter character);
```

My take turn method

```
public static void runCombatLoop(Monster monster){

    while (isPlayerAlive()&& isMonsterAlive(monster))
    {
        GameCharacter player = new Player();
        Monster enemy = new Monster(){};
        enemy.Monster();

        GameCharacter.takeTurn(player);
        GameCharacter.takeTurn(enemy);
    }


}// run combat loop end
```

Comment: `takeTurn` is not `static`, you must call it on an instance of `GameCharacter`, shouldn't it be `player.takeTurn`, but then, I don't know why you would pass another `GameCharacter` to it?

Comment: Go through the inheritance topic of java

Comment: That code wouldn't compile

Comment: Once you have `player.takeTurn()` and `enemy.takeTurn()`, your run time will know by the first time when you initialized `new Player()` or so on. When you are initializing, a new instance of Player will be created and that will be referred when takeTurn is called.

Comment: RunDungeon.java:267: error: method takeTurn in class GameCharacter cannot be applied to given types;
        player.takeTurn();
              ^
  required: GameCharacter
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

is the error message. And I have read through the inheritance topic many times. I'm just really confused about super super classes.

Comment: Please also use proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all inheritance passes from superclass to subclass, including instance variables and methods.

Meaning, if you wanted to "call a superclass method" with "subclass parameters", you simply create an object in the subclass and call your method.

---

For example, in your superclass, you have

`public abstract void takeTurn(GameCharacter character);`

And you have, hypothetically, two subclasses of GameCharacter:

```
public class Player extends GameCharacter { ... }

public class Enemy extends GameCharacter { ... }
```

Now, if you wanted to call `takeTurn` with a Player parameter or an Enemy parameter, you would put them in their respective subclasses.

```
//In Player.java
public class Player extends GameCharacter {
    //instance variables
    
    //methods (only takeTurn shown)
    void takeTurn( Player p ) {
         //take turn definition for Player here
    }
}

//In Enemy.java
public class Enemy extends GameCharacter {
    //instance variables
    
    //methods (only takeTurn shown)
    void takeTurn( Enemy e ) {
         //take turn definition for Enemy here
    }
}
```

---

> An abstract method is **NOT** defined until you specifically **define** it in each respective subclass.
>
> You can think of an ***abstract*** class (methods, too) as a *blueprint* for a class.

In other words, since both `Player` and `Enemy` are subclasses of `GameCharacter`, and `takeTurn( GameCharacter character)` is an abstract method, you can create and call `takeTurn` in each individual class.

Note: You can do this because the abstract method `takeTurn` takes a `GameCharacter`, and both `Player` and `Enemy` extend `GameCharacter`

---

**EDIT**: In order for you to call takeTurn( ... ) in main without creating an object, you must make takeTurn `static`.

General practice recommends you making a `GameCharacter` object with `new`, and calling `takeTurn( ... )` via that object, as I believe you would want multiple characters.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have done this in the respective subclasses, but it won't let me access the methods.

Comment: It won't let you access what methods in what classes? Please be clear (: